# How to show() a bokeh chart from a list of chart objects

Tags: python, bokeh

I am trying to call `show()` function passing a list element as argument, but I getting this error: "

> AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'references'

I'm using jupyter notebook.

Here is my code:

```
from bokeh.charts import HeatMap
from bokeh.charts import output_file, show

b = []
for i,x in enumerate(c):
    df = result_dados[result_dados['Diretoria_2']==c[i]]
    hm = HeatMap(df, y='quest_no', x='respondente', values = 'resposta', \
        stat='mean', width=800, plot_height=600)
    b.append(hm)

output_file('test.html', title="heatmap test")
show(b[11])
```

The elements of the list are all `bokeh.charts.chart.Chart`.

I noticed that if I run the code twice for the same list element, the chart is shown. Any hints of how can I get this to run successfully at the first time?

Comment: can you add the code for "c" ?

Comment: c is a list obtained from a pd data frame: ['Dir1',  'Dir2', 'Dir3', …, 'Dir20’]. The code for c is: c = a.Diretoria.tolist()

Comment: Long after I had the very same error, and discovered that the cause was Jupyter Notebook. Reinstallation resolved.